# How to get online duration of a user by using session?

Tags: yii, php

In yii I need to store the users `_login time`,`logout time` and `total duration logged_`  Using session.

I am new to session concept. I don know how to retrieve the `total logged time`, `login time`, `log out time`. In session table it stores only `id--expire--data`

My code for storing session is

```
protected/config/main.php

            'components'=>array(

    'session'=>array(
            'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',

            'connectionID' => 'db',
            'sessionTableName' => 'dbsession',
        ),
    ),
```

All working fine but data stored in db are encrypted. So I am unable to retrieve the data I need. One more thing what data is stored in session table.

Alternative way I used without session but that also have problem. I used this for getting `login time`, `logout time` and `total duration logged`

I used a table activity with fields

```
id,username,user_activity,url,ip,time
```

Codes to fill datas in table when user login and logout is below

```
protected/controller/sitecontrollers.php

         public function actionLogin()
        {
                /* log in */

                $model=new LoginForm;

                // if it is ajax validation request
                if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
                {
                        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                        Yii::app()->end();
                }

                // collect user input data
                if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
                {
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
                        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
                        if($model->validate() && $model->login())                                                                               
                               {
                                $activity = new Activity;
                                $activity->username = Yii::app()->user->id;                          
                                //$activity->userId = Yii::app()->user->id;
                                $activity->user_activity = "1";
                $activity->url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
                $activity->ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                                // This breaks the site when log in details are wrong
                                $activity->save();
                                if($activity->save())
                                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
                    }                          


                }

                // display the login form
      if(Yii::app()->user->id==null)
      {
                  $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
      }
         else
           {
         throw new CHttpException(404,'User already logged in.');
             }
        }

        /**
         * Logs out the current user and redirect to homepage.
         */
       public function actionLogout()
        {


                // log
                $activity = new Activity;
                $activity->username = Yii::app()->user->id;
                $activity->user_activity = "0";
        $activity->url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        $activity->ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $activity->save();      


                Yii::app()->user->logout();   
                                if($activity->save())                                  

                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
        }
```

In this way all workin fine but when browser closed the application is logged out and a data not entering in to the database.then the calculation of duration is getting wrong. So only I took the method session but don't know how to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you will never do such kind of thing corectly but with some mistake (more or less some minutes, depends on your needs).

#### 1. Keeping alive with page requests

You could send alive status to your ajax page `actionImAlive` and more often you do that, more **precisely** you will tell how long user session was. If you do that *alive thing* 1 time in 5 minutes, you will have duration with ~5min mistake.

1. Add columns t_login, t_last_activity
2. on User login update t_login and t_last_activity with current timestamp
3. On every user new page load check if need to update t_last_activity

   Main Controller *(components/Controller.php)

   ```
   public function keepAlive( ) {
           User::model()->updateByPk( 
               Yii::app()->user->id, 
              // array('t_last_activity' => 'NOW()') //CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            array('t_last_activity' => new CDbExpression('NOW()')) //CURRENT_TIMESTAMP..this working fine 
       );
   }

   // Runs after any action in controller
   public function afterAction($action) {
       self::keepAlive();
       parent::afterAction($action);
   }

   // This action can be reached by ajax every 5min 
   // if user stays in one page long enaugh
   // (write javascript..)
   public function actionImAlive() {
       self::keepAlive();
   }
   ```
4. Above code updates t_last_activity every time user loads new page, but you could do it every 5min by saving last activity timestmap in user session and check it before executing keepAlive() function

   **Other controllers**

   All other controllers uses Controller class as parent

   ```
   SiteController extends Controller
   MyController extends Controller
   SomeController extends Controller
   ```

#### 2. For user display only (calculates duration from login time to now: `now() - t_login`)

If you want to display this session duration to user (why you should want to do this I don't know, but anyway..) you could just add `t_login` column to User table and calculate duration time on a fly.

These was top of my head.

Comment: @briiC.Ivi am totally new please elobrate your aswer its confusing..if you can give some sample..or if you understand my needs kindly ive some other suggestion.it may help full o me

Comment: tried to explain more. Hope its get more clear and ask again if needs to explain more (i didn't include *save timestamp in session* part).

Comment: hi thanks i am busy with some other important project i will intimate you tomorrow after i check above one...and thanks alot again..

Comment: @ briiC.lv  i just read your answer but didn't test.i have a question.my application is used to **track the employees activity in a company**.calculation of logged duration is use to track the overall **duration of working hour by loggedin session**.

Comment: .so is that possible to get total duration of a user per month and per year like wise .i have doubt in your code that its updating the time every login?.thats why i am asking..or other than this shall i save data in another table?.

Comment: @ briiC.lv hi its worked out for taken current login  duration...my need of use is as commented to you before.

Comment: thats nice you figure it out. If you find some other solution that worked to you maybe comment later (after month, two or 6) :)

Comment: hi i got solution i just added a model to the table and followed your procedure...thanks alot